# Custom exit prompt dialog in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt4, python-3.4

I'm trying to create custom exit prompt dialog, which should do the following:

- It has Yes, No buttons along with "Save new settings" checkbox item
- When I click **Yes**, the dialog should shutdown the main program
- When I click **No**, the dialog should come back to the main program

So, nothing special, but when I click **No** it closes the main program.
I've tried to use

```
app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(False)
```

but in this case the main window is hidden and the program is "stuck".
Here is the code.

```
class AreYouSure(QtGui.QDialog):

    saved = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self):
        super(AreYouSure, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()
        self.retranslateUI()
        self.initActions()

    def initUI(self):
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        hor_lay = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.label = QtGui.QLabel()
        self.check_item = QtGui.QCheckBox()
        self.yes = QtGui.QPushButton()
        self.no = QtGui.QPushButton()
        hor_lay.addWidget(self.yes)
        hor_lay.addWidget(self.no)
        layout.addWidget(self.check_item)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addLayout(hor_lay)
        self.setLayout(layout)

    def retranslateUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle("Exit")
        self.label.setText("Are you sure to quit?")
        self.yes.setText("Yes")
        self.no.setText("No")
        self.check_item.setText("Save e-mail/password")

    def exit(self):
        if self.check_item.isChecked():
            self.saved.emit()
        QtGui.QApplication.quit()

    def initActions(self):
        self.yes.clicked.connect(self.exit)
        self.no.clicked.connect(self.close)
```

and in MainWindow

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
        a = AreYouSure()
        a.saved.connect(self.saveDefaults)
        a.exec_()

def saveDefaults(self):
        '''save default email and password'''
        self.settings = QtCore.QSettings(DEFAULT_NAME, QtCore.QSettings.IniFormat)
        self.settings.setValue("email", self.email_edit.text())
        self.settings.setValue("password", self.pass_edit.text())
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that you should add `event.ignore()` is that all QEvent is accepted by default (also means you don't need to call `event.accept()`): [doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qevent.html)

Answer (score 1):

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
        a = AreYouSure()
        a.saved.connect(self.saveDefaults)
        a.exec_()
        event.ignore()
```

Adding **event.ignore()** solved the issue. Can anyone explain, why?
CloseEvent is overridden and shouldn't accept event, should it?